# Google Cloud Platform - forward ports to multiple SQL instances

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, google-vpc

I am running multiple SQL instances in Google Cloud Platform (GCP). I have multiple masters with some read-replicas. Each instance has an private IP-address based on the region it is in, all instances use the same stock MySQL port (3306).

In the same VPC I have a few compute engines that can connect to each of the SQL instance without any problems. But I also have a few clients that need to connect from outside the VPC, through the internet so to say.

The question is how can I forward certain ports to the right internal IP-address in my VPC? IE:

```
x.x.x.x:12345 -> 10.x.x.1:3306
x.x.x.x:23456 -> 10.x.x.2:3306
x.x.x.x:34567 -> 10.x.x.3:3306
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'protocol forwarding for private regional forwarding rules' [enter here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/protocol-forwarding#privateVIPs) with 'VPC subnet ranges' [enter here](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc#manually_created_subnet_ip_ranges) . Use this feature to configure private forwarding rules that send TCP or UDP traffic to a target instance in the same region. You can also switch private regional forwarding rules from using target instances to backend services and vice versa

Comment: This solution only works for internal IP, not for external client, right?

Comment: But you need 1 loadbalancer per forwarding rule no? How do you perform the route according with the source IP?

Comment: Yes, [forwarding](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/protocol-forwarding#forwardingrules) rules need specific target pools (loadbalancer) or target instances (protocol forwarding). In order to perform route, please follow the [doc](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/routes#routeselection).

Comment: I dont need general forwarding rules, as they dont let me forward port X on the public IP to port Y on a private IP. Or am I wrong here?

Comment: Besides, the loadbalancer only let me forward to VM instances or instance groups. Not to SQL instances.

Comment: @Nhz did you try to build a [NEG](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/negs)

Comment: @Mahboob, in any case, the protocol forwarding only forward the traffic to the correct instance/pool, but never change the port. The constraint in the question is not addressed, right?

Comment: @Nhz After researching in the public document, I noticed this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tio73RwPj9U), let me know if this helps you.

Comment: @Mahboob No this does not answer my question. I know I can connect throught the internal network, but I want to connect from outside the internal network through a normal mysql-connection, for instance with MySQL Workbench. I want to connect to all mysql instances, with just one firewall defending it. So when firewall settings change, I dont need to change them on all instances, just in one firewall.

Comment: - We have a [document1](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/admin-tools#workbench) for connecting to a Cloud SQL instance with mysql workbench that you may follow. As stated in the document[1], you need to add your mysql workbench machine’s IP address as an authorized network for your Cloud SQL instance which the steps are elaborated in this [document](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/authorize-networks#authorized-networks).

Comment: As said before, I want to run multiple SQL instances behind one firewall. So that I dont have to manage a firewall for every instance. I have over 50 different users connecting to over 10 SQL instances. If I have to manage a firewall for every instance, thats quite a lot of work.